# Laravel 6 error 429: X-Ratelimit-Remaining deducts higher than expected

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, single-page-application, http-status-code-429

Hello I am using Laravel Framework 6.18.23 and when ever my Vue app connects to the API it deducts more than what I expected.

Here is the sample screenshot below

[image]

As you can see I tried to login in my app 3 consecutively but laravel deducts more than 3 on a x-ratelimit-remaining. Additionally the x-ratelimit-remaining not resetting after 1 minute.

Any idea what might be the reason?

I tried php artisan cache:clear but still the issue exists

This issue only exist in production environment not in nonprod or preprod but I don't know where to start investigating

Comment: What are the differences between the production and preproduction.  / Did it was working fine before? If yes, did you make some changes? / Do you have access log enabled ? Since it's production you can't exclude the possibility a bot is trying to brute-force the password. / Does all the accounts are affected or only yours?

Comment: The main difference i see in preprod and prod is the production is available in the internet while our preprod is only available in our intranet. Yes I have access log enabled. And everyone accessing site is affected even if they are not logged in.

Thanks for pointing access_log upon checking 429 response is very common when users access our site since we deployed. I think we will just disabled the throttle request I'm just actually curious why x-ratelimit-remaining deducts a big number on every api request

Comment: My bad. I mixed request throttle (which is per IP) and auth throttle (which is per email). Are users accessing the website share the same IP? In that case, I believe you can use a custom Throttle to choose different source like the session.

Comment: Ohhhhhh. Do you think because we are using the same VPN in our comapny it resulted to us having the same IP address?

Comment: Yes, exactly that!

Comment: Thanks man! I think that's my problem, I'll update you when I confirmed it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Clément Baconnier comments for pointing me in the right direction. It turns out that our laravel was hosted in a proxy server so everyone who access our site has the same ip address so everyone share the 60 request per minute limitation on laravel ThrottleRequests.php

[image]